# Highlight a new feature in android app with an imageview and make it look normal after 1 click?

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I need to add a new feature in my app and I have to put an image on the side of the layout. Such that the feature gets highlighted.
But, even if I write the code to make the view's visibility gone after one click. It still appears next time, when the app gets opened.
So, can anyone tell me how to do this correctly ??
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: share your java code and i'm fix it

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Hello Parul. When you want to show this exactly? If you want start the app with this image with visibility gone, you can set it in the xml android:visibility="gone" and only change it when you are making click

Comment: @juanjo Berenguer I want the app to start with the image and after one click it shouuld never appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should solve your problem

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imgTarget;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean imageVisible = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("img_visible",true);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        imgTarget = findViewById(R.id.imgTarget);

        if (!imageVisible){
            imgTarget.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(imageVisible){
                    imgTarget.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("img_visible",false).apply();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: But I want the targetImage to appear only once. Not in next call of onCreate().

Comment: I know that, i created it before you replied the comment, i am changing the code

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, i'm guessing you've the gone after 1 click part done already.

Use SharedPreferences to see if the app has already been opened. 
If yes, then set the Visibility to `View.GONE` in onCreate after you find the id. Otherwise, show it. Feel free to ask if there's anything else.

Comment: Yes, I think this should work.Can you please tell how to check if the app is opened for the first time? by using a flag value or something else?

Comment: agreed with @Jacob. Are you using listview or recyclerview to show new items in your app, if yes then the solution would be different.Feel free to ask. Thanks

Comment: yes, the layout is under gridview. But that is not the issue.

Comment: @ParulMathur I've added a code you can use. Please accept and upvote this  answer and close this question.

Comment: I am applying this code @JacobCelestine , I will accept it once it runs. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code and xml? I'll be able to take a look then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Not enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Sure. Anyway, feel free to ping me if you need help some other time.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app connected to a database like sql, firebase or something else,  if so you can create a counter variable in your database and control your view accordingly .

Comment: no, its an offline app. Yes, I am looking for a possible solution. Thanks.

Comment: In such a case, the only possible way is to use shared preferences.